# Any way to control FP precision in desktop OpenGL?

Tags: windows, opengl, precision, nvidia

Is it possible to force a GPU to use `highp float`s in shaders when the OpenGL version being used is 2.0? I know that precision modifiers are basically a GLES concept, but `float`s do seem to use `mediump` by default on a desktop I was provided for testing, and it`s driving me nuts.

I`ve stumbled across that problem while running my GL project under Win10 with a GTX1070 GPU (driver version 23.21.13-9135). I don`t even have `#version` set in my shaders, so I expected the precision to be automatically maxed out.

AFAIK, OpenGL 2.x standard does not define any ways to hint the GPU that at least 20 of 24 mantissa bits are significant (passing integers through floats, since GL 2.0 cannot operate on integers natively), but that`s the first time in 3++ years that I`ve seen a desktop GPU do such a thing, so I`ve never even thought it possible.

Help needed.

Comment: How do you know that `mediump` floats are used? Even if it would be glsl-es, it would be implementation defined which bitwidth a highp float has. For desktop-gl, there is no such thing as precision qualifiers. I would be rather surprised when a GTX1070 would not use 32bit IEEE floats. Also: When no version is specified, the shader is treated as version 1.10. This does not mean that precision is maxed out.

Comment: @BDL I know that because I see that the sprites being drawn fetch wrong texels, resulting in garbled output, as if only ~16 bits of mantissa made it through the pipeline. I am well aware that precision qualifiers do not exist in desktop OpenGL, just like I stated in the question.

Comment: For OpenGL 2.0, the only guarantee about floating point values on can get is defined by Section 2.1.1 of the [OpenGL 2.0 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec20.pdf). If you need better guarantees, you will have to use at least version 330. Between 150 and 330 the sentence: " It is not required that the
precision of internal processing match the IEEE floating-point specification" was changed to "Floating-point variables
within a shader are also encoded according to the IEEE 754 specification for single-precision floatingpoint
values."

Comment: @BDL understood, thank you. Well, seems like I have to work it around, and never fill floats to capacity… =(

Comment: It dawned on me that the problem has always been present in my code, but only GTX1070 allowed it to reveal itself. It was the only GPU I tested that supported 3D textures with 4096x4096 layers, addressing which takes up to 24 bits.

Comment: Even a IEEE float only has 23 explicitly stored mantissa bits. So I guess you are right with the overflow theory.